# Flutter not working in Visual studio Code.. can't find Flutter SDK

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I cant get flutter to work, I'm using visual studio and when I run flutter doctor I get this message, "Could not find a Flutter SDK. Please ensure flutter is installed and in your PATH (you may need to restart)."

I've tried making the path for flutter up to bin and it did not work. I uninstalled and re-installed and still did not work. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you _show_ where your flulter is installed and what exactly you mean by "_making the path for flutter up to bin_"?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on recent versions of the Dart extension, this error message should have a "Locate SDK" button that allows you to browse to where you downloaded the Flutter SDK to, then it should be located without any errors next time.